# Zend_PDF template Zend_Pdf::load

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to create a PDF with a template using Zend_Framework.

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('/..../pdf-template.pdf');
```

This creates the following error:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Pdf_ElementFactory::fetch() in /.../Zend/Pdf/Element/Reference.php on line 164**

this is in the _dereference Method :
line 164:

```
if (($obj = $this->_factory->fetch($this->_objNum . ' ' . $this->_genNum)) === null) {
            $obj = $this->_context->getParser()->getObject(
                           $this->_context->getRefTable()->getOffset($this->_objNum . ' ' . $this->_genNum . ' R'),
                           $this->_context
                                                          );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird - are you sure you haven't changed the Zend class? My `_dereference` uses `fetchObject`, and I confirmed there is a method called `fetchObject` in `ElementFactory.php`:

```
if (($obj = $this->_factory->fetchObject($this->_objNum . ' ' . $this->_genNum)) === null)
```

If you haven't changed it, it might be worth upgrading your Zend version.

Comment: yes, never touched Zend Files...  * @version    $Id: Reference.php 18993 2009-11-15 17:09:16Z alexander $

Comment: How very strange. If you care, it's worth checking the revisions to see if this code was changed, and if so when, otherwise it may be worth upgrading to the next Zend release after the one you're currently on

Comment: I just changed fetch to fetchObject and it works! thanks dKen!

Comment: No problem. I would be wary of changing Zend code directly though, because you literally have no idea of what knock-on effects it may have. I still suggest you update your entire Zend library. Also, if this helped, can you accept my answer? Thanks :)